# Tax obligations for deemed non-residents in Canada

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada, non-resident, canada-revenue-agency

I live (and I'm resident) in a European country (Austria, that has a tax agreement with Canada) and spent 8 months in Canada last year (2022) due to a research stay (I worked on my Master Thesis in a research group there). I had a working permit (under the International Experience Canada Program) but didn't get an ordinary pay but was paid a scholarship. I got a T4A tax document for confirmation.

Since I spent more than 183 days in Canada I had to clarify with the authorities about my tax situation. The Canadian Tax Authorities decided that I have not established residental ties with Canada, since (among others) I worked in Austria prior and after my stay in Canada. Thus, they wrote me that I am considered as a deemed non-resident.

If I understand correctly, as a deemed non-resident the [same rules apply to me as for non-residents](https://httpshttps://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/international-non-residents/individuals-leaving-entering-canada-non-residents/deemed-residents.html). Following the Canadian Government's site further, it thus tells me to use the tax package for [non-residents](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/tax-packages-years/general-income-tax-benefit-package/non-residents.html). As I read it, as a deemed non-resident I may be subject to non-resident withholding tax on interest, dividend, rental and pension income received from Canadian sources.

While having my tax status clarified was an important first step, I am still somehow confused about what that means for me. Thus, after this long introduction, I have a couple of questions and hope some of you can help me!

1. I received very little interest (<5 CAD) on my Canadian Bank account and I hold shares of one Canadian Company that pays dividend (summig up to <100€/year) (via my European bank). At least in Europe I am used to banks only paying out interest minus taxes to my account(and even if they didn't can be only a few Cents). For the dividends I am sure that I only received dividends minus taxes (netto dividend). Am I right, that this means there is no reason for me to file a tax return, as everything is already payed and done or minor?
2. As mentioned, I obtained a (tax free) stipend (of magnitude 15k CAD), as reported on my T4A file, Box-Case 105. Do I have to report that somewhere? If yes, is [Shedule 11: Federal Tuition, Education, and
   Textbook Amounts and Canada Training Credit](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/cra-arc/formspubs/pbg/5005-s11/5005-s11-22e.pdf) the right place? If yes, where exactly? Since I haven't paid tuition, most of the lines seem not to apply to me. On the other hand, I couldn't find any better document...
3. During my research about my tax situation, I read on some webpage that even as a deemed non-resident I have to tell Canadian Authorities my world income (so basically my employment income in Europe and my capital incomes [held at my European bank])[using this form](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/cra-arc/formspubs/pbg/5013-sa/5013-sa-22e.pdf). While this form seems to be straight-forward, I couldn't find any clear statement on an official webpage that tells me I even have to report my world-income. So, is this even true?
4. In case the answers to 1)-3) are negative, is there any reason I should nevertheless file any kind of tax report? Is there any tax refund I could expect? (I know from my home country that things like negative tax exist, but I am not sure if any of that applies to deemed non-residents).

Thank you very much in advance for your help! I really invested quite some time to learn about the Canadian tax system, read tons of webpages explaining things and went over many documents. However, in the end, I am still not entirely sure and would appreciate any answers, hints and comments!

Comment: If you can add some specifics, that starts to make this answerable - as is, vagueness makes it hard to know what details are irrelevant and which are relevant. ie: did you earn $5 interest or $5,000? Also, which tax years are involved? Just 2022, or also into 2023? Have your other european tax returns been filed? What country are you actually from? The tax treaty for country A could be meaningfully different from country B; unfortunately educational stipends can be one of those things that is particularly tricky, especially relative to the values usually involved. As is, this is unanswerable.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Thank you for your comment! I've edited my main post and added the information. My country of residence is Austria, the mentioned interest is of magnitude <5 CAD, dividends are of magnitude <100€ (before tax) and only tax year 2022 is involved. I entered and left Canada in 2022. So, in my opinion the only "major" thing should be the stipend.

Comment: how much was the stipend? Again, effort put to proper resolution is very different for 15k vs 500.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon The stipend was about 15000CAD